# How to get a range of text to appear as opposed to the word "Range"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get certain company names to send to my email every day. I have set up the trigger and whatnot, but when I run the code, since I am trying to use a range of data, the email just says "Range," as opposed to the company names themselves.

I have tried various formatting, such as only saying A3:A9 as opposed to "A3:A9".

```
function EmailCheck() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A9")

MailApp.sendEmail("zburton@usgbc.org", "Emails for Today!", range)
}
```

I would like the email to say the words in range A3:A9, but right now it just says A3:A9

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem:

At the moment you're only getting a range object, not the values inside the range object.

---

#### Solution:

You need to pass your range to `.getValues()` to achieve your goal.

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A3:A9");
var values = range.getValues();

MailApp.sendEmail("zburton@usgbc.org", "Emails for Today!", values);
```

---

#### References:

- [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())